# SpringBoot: EclipseLink with H2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I have this class:

```
   @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.pasits.repository")
    @Slf4j
    @Configuration
    public class EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    
        protected EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration(
                DataSource dataSource,
                JpaProperties properties,
                ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager) {
    
            super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
            return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        }
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public static JpaProperties properties() {
            final JpaProperties jpaProperties = new JpaProperties();
            jpaProperties.setShowSql(true);
            jpaProperties.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect ");
            return jpaProperties;
        }
    
    ...
    }
```

but when I start the app, I have this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7042] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Database platform class [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] not found.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.Platform
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:563)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:680)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.getMetamodel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
```

Comment: Defining `jpaProperties.setProperties​(Map<String,​String> properties)`, like this `map.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect")`, should be a good approach...

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: Why would you pass in a Hibernate class (org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect) to EclipseLink to use as an EclipseLink DatabasePlatform class?  As the errors states, EclipseLink needs classes that implement org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.Platform. I believe if you leave it blank, EclipseLink will try to auto detect which databasePlatform class to use. Otherwise, pick something from the EclipseLInk docs that is appropriate for h2 (org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database. H2Platform?)